# Jquery async calls in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Jquery and have some code which loops through an array and loads HTML from an ajax request on each iteration of the loop:

```
$.each(arr, function (data) {
    $.get('/Quote/LoadQuoteItemCost', { 'i': i }, function (html) {
        $('#myTable).append(html);
        // There are a few more lines which modify the html which I've left out
    });
    i++;
});
```

My problem is that the responses are being appende to #myTable in random order, I assume due to the async nature of JQuery.  How can I ensure my responses are appended to my table in the order that they are iterated through the array?

I've tried async = false, but it's depreciated in my browser (and have seen many posts saying not to use it)

Comment: send back the id and collect the responses till all previous ids are received. if so: append. if not: wait for the next response

Comment: or use the jquery equivalent of `Promise.all` - so once all `$.get` run, you can loop through the results in the order **you** control - assuming jqueery even has a `Promise.all` equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using native (to some browsers) Promise

```
Promise.all(arr.map(function(data, i) {
    return $.get('/Quote/LoadQuoteItemCost', { 'i': i });
})).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function (html, n) {
        var data = arr[n];
        $('#myTable').append(html);
        ...
    });
});
```

jQuery's equivalent seems to be `$.when`, however, it accepts multiple (promise) arguments (rather than an array of Promises), and the then function receives multiple "results", rather than a single array of results - so the whole procedure would be a bit different from the "(almost) pure JS" above - but that should get you going

edit: I feel dirty doing it, but I'm fairly confident this will do what you want using more jQuery than I'm comfortable doing :p

```
$.when.apply(null, $.map(arr, function(data, i) {
    return $.get('/Quote/LoadQuoteItemCost', { 'i': i });
})).then(function() {
    $.each(arguments, function (n, html) {
        var data = arr[n];
        $('#myTable').append(html);
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: The JQuery solution is working really well, but the browser is printing out 'success' on the page - where can I stop that?

Comment: clearly the "success" is part of the html that is coming back from $.get console.log the html parameter to see what it is

Comment: Strangely, html is an array with [0] being the html, [1] being 'success' and [2] just being an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

The concept I explained in the comments now in a fiddle and code:

```
var responses = [],
    highestNumber = -1,
    highestReceivedNumber = -1;
function handleResponse(id, data) {
    highestReceivedNumber = Math.max(highestReceivedNumber, id);
    responses[id] = data;
    if(id===highestNumber+1)
        for(i=id;i<=highestReceivedNumber;i++)
            if(!responses[i]) return;
            else $('div:eq(0)').append(responses[i]) && highestNumber++;
}
```

take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4udeg6wz/

Answer (score 0):

You should make other calls to the $.get in preceeding $.get's success call back recursively & maintain counter/variable to halt the recursion when your whole array 'arr' is consumed. 
This way the next $.get will only be initiated once the previous $.get's response has returned.

Comment: this costs a LOT of time. not a good solution. catch the results are the better way to do that. I won't down vote your answer, because it's a regular solution, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yes you are right, this would basically mimic the behavior of a synchronous call somehow.